# How to replace last 4 digits in Pandas Dataframe by 0101 if they are 9999 (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
OrdNo  year
1     20059999
2     20070830
3     20070719
4     20030719
5     20039999
6     20070911
7     20050918
8     20070816
9     20069999
```

How to replace last 4 digits in the Pandas Dataframe by 0101 if they are 9999?

Thanks

Comment: Is `year` a string or numeric column? If it's numeric, check whether `year %10000==9999`. To modify, `(year // 10000) + 101`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `year` column is of type `str`:

```
df["year"] = df["year"].str.replace("(9999)$", "0101")
```

If it is of `numeric` type

```
df["year"] = pd.to_numeric(df["year"].astype(str).str.replace("(9999)$", "0101"), errors="coerce")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script which explains how to approach this. Note that this is a very stretched out version and it probaly can and should be compacted, but I have tried to make it as clear as possible to follow.
Also, a good way of practice if you're a beginning developer is to think out some steps to approach the issue in your head (or write it down) and dive into the documentation of the libraries to try and find a good solution.

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating dataframe
data = [[1, 20059999], [2, 20070830], [3, 20070719], [4, 20030719], [5, 20039999], [6, 20070911], [7, 20050918], [8, 20070816], [9, 20069999]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['OrdNo', 'year'])

# Iterating through dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Here we take the columns from the row we are in right now
    OrdNo = row['OrdNo']
    year = row['year']

    # Taking last four digits from year int. We need to convert the year int to string to do this. -4: basically
    # tells the code to start at the end (-), move 4 characters back (4) and return everything from that point to the
    # end (:)
    lastfour = str(year)[-4:]

    # Check if last four digits are 9999 (as string, because lastfour is a string)
    if lastfour == "9999":
        # If true, replace the 9999 with 0101
        # First we take the year but remove the last four digits (the 9999)
        year = str(year)[:-4]

        # Then we add 0101 to the year
        newyear = year + "0101"

        # Now convert it back to int
        newyear = int(newyear)

        # And put it back in the dataframe
        # We use loc to find based on the OrdNo and then we replace the year column by our new value
        df.loc[df['OrdNo'] == OrdNo, 'year'] = newyear

# Lets print the result
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: you should avoid iterrows, it is bad to suggest people use iterrows for a problem like this (it should only be used as a last resort)